# Bin To Dec code explaination

Tags: java, binary, decimal

T student, my teacher said that the codes are okay.. but she asked me that how come binary input 00101 becomes 5.0 dec.
i really need help. i dont know how to explain how 00101 bin becomes 5.0
i tried many calculations like.

5(chararraylength)-3(index)-1 * math.pow = 4

i cant get the last the number that makes my 4 into 5.o dec.

```
char[] charArray = binary.toCharArray(); 
double answer = 0; 
for (double index = 0; index < charArray.length; index++){
  if (charArray[(int)index] == '1') {
    answer = answer + Math.pow(2.0, (charArray.length - index - 1));
```

Comment: See [Binary number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Decimal)

Comment: i know to go convert bin to dec in paper or just looking at it. i just need to refer to my codes.

Comment: to get powers of 2 use `1 << n`, **don't** use `pow`

Answer (score 0):

You use `Math.pow()` which operates on doubles, this is therefore normal.

Either print `(int) answer` or use this instead:

```
final int size = charArray.length;
char c;
int answer = 0;

for (int index = size; index > 0; index++) {
    if (charArray[index] == '1')
        answer++;
    answer <<= 1;
}
```

Also note that array indices are `int`s, so your `index` variable should be an int.

Comment: my codes works, i just need explainations why 00101 gets 5.0 dec, my teacher said that i just have to refer to my codes and i dont know why i made this kind of codes then i cant explain how 00101 gets 5.0 :D

Comment: It is because your print a double, that is why.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but here is the calculation the program makes:

00101 means
 0*2^4 +  0*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 0* 2^1 + 1* 2^0
= 0*16 + 0*8 + 1*4 + 0*2 + 1*1 = 5

More details at  [Wikipedia Binary_number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Decimal)

Comment: it should be 5digits as you can see 00101 has 5digits thats the charArray.length
so it should be 5-0-1 ^2 .. 5-1-1^2... 5-2.1^2... 5-3-1^2... 5-4-1^2..

Comment: Ok your look starts with the lowest bit: `1* 2^0 + 0* 2^1 + 1*2^2 + 0*2^3 + 0*2^4`. But it seams I do not understand what your problem is.